# Running a macro a specific day at a specific time range in Ms Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have my VBA functions in a module. I call my function from a Macro. I have it in the *autoexec* macro. So everytime my database is opened, it runs the function. That works great so far.

Now I am trying to make the function run **only** on Monday mornings at a specific time range, for example: Mondays between 8Am - 12:00PM, *not everyday* since the database needs to be updated **only on Mondays**.. I can't find a way to do it. My function code is below:

```
Public Function DownloadFromS()
    On Error GoTo DownloadErrorHandler

    Dim stDocName As String
    stDocName = "getThemFromS"
    DoCmd.RunMacro stDocName
Exit_DownloadS:
    Exit Function
DownloadErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Sorry Sto is offline, re-establish our connection"
    Resume Exit_DownloadS
End Function
```

I am fairly new to VBA so it is a bit hard to wrap my head around it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the current date for its weekday using the `Weekday()` function and the times, as @HansUP was suggesting. The critical part is making sure the procedure is run only once, not every time you open the app. So what you need to do is make sure the app knows if you have previously run it that day.

My solution would look like this:

- I would have a table with one field, i.e. 'ExectureProcedure' of type `Boolean` and only one row, so the table would look like this:

> ```
>  ========================
> | ID | ProcedureExecuted |
> |====|===================| 
> | 1  |      False        |
>  ========================
> ```

- Each time you run check the conditions and the time and weekday does **NOT** meet your criteria, you set the value in this table to `False`, otherwise you leave it.
- You set the value to `True` only after the procedure finishes.

Pseudo code, merely for illustration:

> ```
> If [ExecuteConditionsOK] = True AND [ProcedureExecuted] = False Then
>    Run your procedure
>    Set [ProcedureExecuted] to True
> Elseif [ExecuteConditionsOK] = False Then
>    Set [ProcedureExecuted] to False
> End if
> ```

In short, the procedure will only run if the `ProcedureExecuted` flag is false, which can only be set when the date does not meet your conditions, so the app will run it the next time when it will.

I hope this solution is clear as I didn't have time to write the actual VBA code, but from the top of my head, you will need to use these functions: `Weekday`, `DLookup`. If you'll struggle, post it in the comments.